# how to pass a string variable to the where clause in dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have to deploy my sql script and for that I have defined variable in one file and the create script in another file.

File 1:

**Define_Variable.sql**

```
DEFINE hr_SCHEMA = hr;
```

File 2:

**Createfile.sql**

```
@Define_variable.sql

declare
v_str varchar2(3000);
lc_cnt number;
BEGIN
   v_str :='select count(1) into l_cnt from dba_tab_cols where owner=''' || &hr_SCHEMA ||''' and TABLE_NAME=''employees''';
   execute immediate v_str;
   IF l_cnt = 0 then

   -----perform some operations
   end if;
end ;
   /
```

I'm getting the following error.
`ORA-06550` and `PLS-00201: identifier 'hr' must be declared`.
Here the value is getting substituted but how to write the value within quotes. Like my output should execute

```
select count(1) into l_cnt from dba_tab_cols where owner= 'hr' and TABLE_NAME='employees';
```

This is just an example of my big script, but the objective is how to substiture a string varible in a where query of a dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to user bind variables and the using clause.

```
   declare
   v_str  varchar2(3000);
   lc_cnt number;
begin
   v_str := 'select count(1) from dba_tab_cols where owner=:owner and TABLE_NAME=''employees''';
   execute immediate v_str into l_cnt using '&HR_schema';
   if l_cnt = 0
   then
      -----perform some operations
   end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

***Alternatively*, you can use the variable inside the SQL string, just remember to add the quotes** `where owner= ''&HR_schema''`

```
set serveroutput on
define HR_schema = hr

    declare
       v_str  varchar2(3000);
       l_cnt number;
    begin
       --v_str := 'select count(1) from dba_tab_cols where owner=:owner and TABLE_NAME=''employees''';
       v_str := 'select count(1) from dba_tab_cols where owner= ''&HR_schema'' and TABLE_NAME=''employees''';
       execute immediate v_str into l_cnt ; --using '&HR_schema';
       if l_cnt = 0
       then
         dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt);
          -----perform some operations
       end if;
    end;
```

Comment: The performance gain here might be quite marginal, since the bind variable solution would be more performant by preventing a hard parse with succesive executions of the SQL wich is not be the case here. On the other side, the use of bind variables can affect the performance if you want to take advantage of Histograms. E.G in the first parse you might have an unpolar value for the variable, makint the CBO choose to use the index, whereas succesful executions could come with popular values. In this case, several hard parses could be a better solution than running an SQL with a suboptimal plan

Comment: @Rene - I don't think the bind issues will become significant until the query is run many times for many different schemas.